# While building DRAMPower command "make -j4" gives error UBUNTU

Tags: build, gem5

I want to build DRAMPower for GEM5 and it gives error when i run the command "make -j4"

Downloaded DRAMPower.zip and then after unzipping it running the make command

The Error which is get is:

```
g++ -O -W -pedantic-errors -Wextra -Werror -Wformat -Wformat-
nonliteral -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wall -Werror -g
-std=c++0x -MMD -MF src/TraceParser.d -iquote src -o src/TraceParser.o
-c src/TraceParser.cc
g++ -O -W -pedantic-errors -Wextra -Werror -Wformat -Wformat-
nonliteral -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wall -Werror -g -std=c++0x
-MMD -MF src/CmdScheduler.d -iquote src -o src/CmdScheduler.o -c
src/CmdScheduler.cc
g++ -O -W -pedantic-errors -Wextra -Werror -Wformat -Wformat-
nonliteral -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wall -Werror -g
-std=c++0x -MMD -MF src/cli/drampower.d -iquote src -o
src/cli/drampower.o -c src/cli/drampower.cc
g++ -O -W -pedantic-errors -Wextra -Werror -Wformat -Wformat-
nonliteral -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wall -Werror -g
-std=c++0x -MMD -MF src/libdrampower/LibDRAMPower.d -iquote src -o
src/libdrampower/LibDRAMPower.o -c src/libdrampower/LibDRAMPower.cc
In file included from src/CommandAnalysis.h:55:0, from 
src/TraceParser.h:46,
from src/TraceParser.cc:37:
src/Utils.h:49:1: error: dynamic exception specifications are
deprecated in C++11 [-Werror=deprecated]
throw(std::runtime_error)
In file included from src/CommandAnalysis.h:55:0,
from src/libdrampower/LibDRAMPower.h:48,
from src/libdrampower/LibDRAMPower.cc:42:
src/Utils.h:49:1: error: dynamic exception specifications are
deprecated in C++11 [-Werror=deprecated]
throw(std::runtime_error)
src/Utils.h:49:1: error: dynamic exception specifications are
deprecated in C++11 [-Werror=deprecated]
throw(std::runtime_error)
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:106: recipe for target 'src/libdrampower/LibDRAMPower.o'
failed
make: *** [src/libdrampower/LibDRAMPower.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:106: recipe for target 'src/cli/drampower.o' failed 
make: *** [src/cli/drampower.o] Error 1
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:106: recipe for target 'src/TraceParser.o' failed
make: *** [src/TraceParser.o] Error 1
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:102: recipe for target 'src/CmdScheduler.o' failed
make: *** [src/CmdScheduler.o] Error 1
```

Comment: I have the following advice: open an upstream ticket: https://github.com/tukl-msd/DRAMPower/issues , and give your Ubuntu version and the git SHA of DRAMPower used.